# explode after numeric ID

Tags: php

Basically, I have a text document which I'm trying to parse "line by line" using PHP so I can do stuff with it, Basically I have a text document with a layout of the following

```
1 Team name
2 Fancy Team
3 My Team
4 Team yay
```

I've tried doing something like the following to try and grab the "ID" in 1 value and the "Team name" in another

```
$file1 = "./list_of_clubs.txt";
$lines = file($file1);
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $getId = explode(" ",$line);
    echo $getId[1]."<br/>";
}
```

When doing this it's exploding all the blankspaces which would parse for example **1 Team name** into **3** different values because it has **3** blankspaces, How would I go about just splitting the **ID** from the **Team name** would I use some form of Regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the explode for the spaces.  Change it to this:

```
$getId = explode(" ",$line, 2);
```

This will make the array have two entries.  The first for the id and the second the team name as you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't. Just limit the exploding.

```
$getId = explode(" ", $line, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

php indexes are `0 based` so your first element is at index 0, you will be able to capture the ID by doing as

```
echo $getId[0]."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the number is at the beginning of each line you can use

```
^\d{1,}
```

within your regexp expression

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work fine

```
echo intval("1 Team name"); //outputs 1
echo intval("35 Team name2"); //outputs 35
```

example:

```
$file1 = "./list_of_clubs.txt";
$lines = file($file1);
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $getId = intval($line);
    echo $getId."<br/>";
}
```